# Criteriabuilder equal on two columns

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-criteria

When writing queries using Criteriabuilder, how to add an equal condition on two columns? e.g.:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<String> cq = cb.createQuery(String.class);
Root<MyTable> root = cq.from(MyTable.class);
Predicate cond = cb.equal(root.get(MyTable_.columnA), root.get(MyTable_.columnB));
```

Doing the above caused an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.SingularAttributePath@236f0ece] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]`

Comment: you mean 2 fields? because JPQL and JPA Criteria do not deal with columns. Post the rest of the criteria code + stack trace of that exception; which then reveals where the problem is. Is it in the where clause? or in the select clause? The code you post is perfectly correct, as far as it goes.

Comment: as DN1 states: where is your `where`? What do you `select`? How do you execute your `cq`?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by creating 2 separate "equal" predicates and using these 2 to create a new predicate with criteriaBuilder.and(predicate1, predicate2);

Your query should look like this:

```
//Sample values to use in where clause
String columnATest = "Jimmy";
String columnBTest = "18";

CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
//This will return a list of MyTable objects.
CriteriaQuery<MyTable> cq = cb.createQuery(MyTable.class);
Root<MyTable> root = cq.from(MyTable.class);
Predicate cond = null; 

//If both columns should match the test values
cond = cb.and(cb.equal(root.get(MyTable_.columnA), columnATest), cb.equal(root.get(MyTable_.columnB), columnBTest));

//If only one of the 2 columns should match the test values
cond = cb.or(cb.equal(root.get(MyTable_.columnA), columnATest), cb.equal(root.get(MyTable_.columnB), columnBTest));

CriteriaQuery cq = criteriaQuery.select(root).where(cond);
TypedQuery typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
List<MyTable> results = (List<MyTable>) typedQuery.getResultList();
```